# SQL Query, for each row in table A should fetch multiple row values (one column) as comma separated in result

Tags: sql, h2

Below I describe the tables and explain the query I'm trying to write,

The Visit Table

```
+--------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+
|   FIELD      |      TYPE        | NULL   | KEY   | DEFAULT   |
+--------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+
| VISIT_ID     | VARCHAR(200)     | NO     | UNI   | NULL      |
| PATIENT      | VARCHAR(45)      | NO     | PRI   | NULL      |
| DOCTOR       | VARCHAR(45)      | NO     | PRI   | NULL      |
| COMPLAINTS   | CLOB(2147483647) | YES    |       | NULL      |
| OBSERVATIONS | CLOB(2147483647) | YES    |       | NULL      |
| REPORTS      | VARCHAR(500)     | YES    |       | NULL      |
| START        | TIMESTAMP(23)    | NO     | PRI   | NULL      |
| END          | TIMESTAMP(23)    | NO     | PRI   | NULL      |
| CREATED_ON   | DATE(8)          | NO     | PRI   | NULL      |
| UPDATED_ON   | DATE(8)          | YES    |       | NULL      |
| STATUS       | VARCHAR(200)     | NO     | PRI   | NULL      |
| TYPE         | VARCHAR(200)     | YES    |       | NULL      |
| DESCRIPTION  | VARCHAR(200)     | NO     |       | NULL      |
+--------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

And Highlight table

```
+----------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+
| FIELD    |      TYPE        | NULL   | KEY   | DEFAULT   |
+----------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+
| VISIT_ID | VARCHAR(200)     | NO     |       | NULL      |
| MATTER   | CLOB(2147483647) | NO     |       | NULL      |
+----------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

Now what I'm trying to query is, for each VISIT from the visit table I want to fetch multiple records in the Highlight table. I can use inner join but it gives me duplicate visit records (see below the SQL)

```
select "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID", "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."DESCRIPTION", "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START", "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS"."MATTER" from "PUBLIC"."VISIT", "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS" where "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID" = "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS"."VISIT_ID" order by "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START" asc
```

this will return the following result:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|     VISIT_ID     | DESCRIPTION |          START          |   MATTER    |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 5178231763512765 | Head Ache   | 2014-05-07 23:08:10.383 | HIGH BP     |
| 5178231763512765 | Head Ache   | 2014-05-07 23:08:10.383 | SUGAR       |
| 5178231763512765 | Head Ache   | 2014-05-07 23:08:10.383 | BROKEN BONE |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

But what I want is something like below:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
|     VISIT_ID     | DESCRIPTION |          START          |          MATTER           |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| 5178231763512765 | Head Ache   | 2014-05-07 23:08:10.383 | HIGH BP~SUGAR~BROKEN BONE |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Some can help how to write query to get the data like the above? the "matter" can be any variable if required.

Comment: is it mysql ? since the query you have should not work on mysql

Comment: No its on H2 database

Comment: so please remove the mysql tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the [group_concat](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#group_concat) aggregate  function (available in mysql and H2). So try this:

```
select "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID"
, "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."DESCRIPTION"
, "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START"
,group_concat( "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS"."MATTER" SEPERATROR ',') as MatterAggre
from "PUBLIC"."VISIT", "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS" 
where "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID" = "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS"."VISIT_ID" 
group by "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID", "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."DESCRIPTION", "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START"
order by "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START" asc
```

Comment: 10+ This worked for me and I did following changes:

   select "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID", "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."DESCRIPTION", "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START", group_concat("PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS"."MATTER" order by "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID" asc, "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."DESCRIPTION" asc, "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START" asc separator '~') "MATTERS" from "PUBLIC"."VISIT", "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS" where "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."VISIT_ID" = "PUBLIC"."HIGHLIGHTS"."VISIT_ID" order by "PUBLIC"."VISIT"."START" asc